# How to use ng repeat correctly in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an old code for a form in angular which contains these lines :

```
      <label for="language">{{'LANGUAGE_LABEL' | translate}}</label>
      <select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
      <option value="en">{{'referencedata.languages.EN' | translate}}</option>
      <option value="nl">{{'referencedata.languages.NL' | translate}}</option>
      </select>
```

And I want to optimize it by using ng repeat (I had read that ng option is better but I never used before...)

So, in my controller, I added a new variable :

```
$scope.languages = [{
      name: "referencedata.languages.EN",
      value: "en"
    }, {
      name: "referencedata.languages.NL",
      value: "nl"
    }]
```

And this my code with using ng repeat :

```
<select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
<option ng-repeat="language in languages track by value" value="{{language.value}}">
{{language.name | translate}}
</option>
```

But it didn't work at all and I got "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]".

Can you tell me please how can I use ng repeat here ? or ng option if you can and if its is more optimized that ng repeat.
thank you!!

Comment: The `ngRepeat:dupes` error you are getting seems inconsistent with the code you posted.

Comment: Read here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You track by `value` but it's not defined. It should be `language.value`.

```
<option ng-repeat="language in languages track by language.value" value="{{language.value}}">
```

Below you can find the ng-options version:

```
<select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue"
        ng-options="language.name for language in languages track by language.value">
</select>
```

And a working snippet with both examples:

```js
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.languages = [{
      name: "referencedata.languages.EN",
      value: "en"
    }, {
      name: "referencedata.languages.NL",
      value: "nl"
    }];
}

angular.module('test', []);
angular.module('test')
  .controller('Main', Main);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="Main">
    <label for="language">{{'LANGUAGE_LABEL'}}</label>
    <select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
      <option ng-repeat="language in languages track by language.value" value="{{language.value}}">
        {{language.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue"
            ng-options="language.name for language in languages track by language.value">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `track by value` code.

```
<select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
<option ng-repeat="language in languages" value="{{language.value}}">
{{language.name | translate}}
</option>
```

Comment: Can you explain why removing `track by` should fix his problem?

Comment: 1 - It's useless to track something that will never change after the first run.

Comment: 2 - `track by value` is bad. It's `track by language.value`

Answer (score 0):

If your list indeed has duplicates, the solution would be to replace `track by value` with `track by $index` instead.

However, the correct way to display options is not by using `ng-repeat`, but using `ng-options` instead, which might save you some code. [See the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for more info and examples.

Comment: I must be going blind, where are the duplicates?

Comment: OP said: "But it didn't work at all and I got "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]"."

Comment: He added his data and there are no duplicates there though, so I'm unsure of what to assume.

Answer (score 0):

You need to suffix property you're tracking by with the name specified in the repeat, in this case language.

```
<select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
<option ng-repeat="language in languages track by language.value" value="{{language.value}}">
{{language.name | translate}}
</option>
```

To use ng-options, which would be a better option it would look like:

```
<select ng-options="language.name | translate for language in languages track by language.value" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue"></select>
```